# Using the wayback machine against link-rot

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, external-links, archive

A lot of people on SO (including me) are against posting links from not reliable resources without posting the main part, because they will eventually get offline and the question/answer will be irrelevant. Same for images not on SO's server.

My question is, if a site has too much about the questions topic (like it's about a specific feature from a language and it consists of multiple paragraphs), then should I post a link from the wayback machine's archive or should I quote the whole thing?

Comment: posting links is FINE. The issue is when the info in your link is the ONLY place in your answer containing that info. Don't post from the wayback, just post from the site. Then summarize the info in your answer, so that even if linkrot happens your answer is more than a signpost to a website.

Comment: The wayback machine is an external dependency just like the original source.

Comment: @Josh it's still on the "stays" part

Comment: at one of my past jobs wayback machine links were blocked, meaning posts that rely solely upon these would be useless to me

Comment: @gnat If that ever again happens, just open Google translate, set the from language to something like Arabic, the to one to English, than paste the blocked url. Google translate will make it unblocked

Comment: @gnat probably a sign one needs to switch firm

Answer (score 6):

> ... then should I post a link from the wayback machine's archive or should I quote the whole thing?

Quote, copy the relevant (code-)examples in any case. Put additional information. (Refer to [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) (link only might be considered VLQ))

Answers (and also questions) are meant to be self contained at Stack Overflow.

A referral link can be considered as a decoration (and you should probably use the wayback archive for it).

> Same for images not on SO's server.

Regarding images, upload them into Stack Overflows imgur repository.