# Host port70.net is MIA — the Wayback Machine has a backup — how to automate updating URLs in Q&A?

Tags: discussion, broken-link

**Update** (2020-12-29 19:00 -07:00): As noted by [gerrit0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7186598/gerrit0) in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404095/host-port70-net-is-mia-the-wayback-machine-has-a-backup-how-to-automate-upda?cb=1#comment817009_404095), it appears that the https://port70.net/ site is back up and running normally.  This specific crisis is averted, but SO should probably have plans to deal with this sort of situation.

Because there was a backup of the site in the Wayback Machine and because the data was basically static (largely unchanging), this would have been relatively easy to resolve.  Other sites that are frequently cited on SO might be harder to deal with.  I think SO should have a general contingency plan for dealing with a much-referenced site going AWOL, even if some of the i's are undotted and some of the t's uncrossed.

---

The site https://port70.net/ has been inaccessible for a while; I first spotted it missing early on 2020-12-27 and it's now late on 2020-12-28 here (so more than 36 hours).  Chrome reports "This site can’t be reached — Check if there is a typo in port70.net — DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

It used to contain an HTML copy of N1570, a near-final committee draft of the C11 standard at:

- [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html)

I have cited and quoted from it in many answers; a number of other people use it too. I hand-counted 23 different users on the first page of 50 results from the query `[c] url:port70.net`, give or take.

Fortunately, there is a recent backup (2020-12-08 09:01:31) of the site on the Wayback Machine (the Web Archive):

- [https://web.archive.org/web/20201208090131/https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20201208090131/https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html)

While it may be too early to panic (I'd give the administrators at least a week into 2021 to reregister the site in case the problem is that the registration has lapsed), it does raise the question:

- How would Stack Overflow handle bulk-converting URL references to a web site that goes missing in action (MIA) into references to the last backup available at the Web Archive?

A search `[c] URL:port70.net` shows 1810 references to `port70.net`, which is more work than can reasonably be done by hand.  The necessary edit is systematic, but that doesn't make it much less onerous.  Some of the URLs are `http://` and some are `https://` — all should be mapped to `https://`.  A single answer may contain multiple references to different parts of N1570.

Related (but distinct) questions include:

- [Using the Wayback Machine against link-rot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337662/using-the-wayback-machine-against-link-rot)
- [I estimate 10% of the links posted here are dead — how do we deal with them?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them)
- [Link to Wayback Machine or original site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284186/link-to-wayback-machine-or-original-site)
- [Fixing up now-bad links to use Wayback Machine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402392/fixing-up-now-bad-links-to-use-wayback-machine)

Comment: The answer, unfortunately, is that we *don't* have an automated solution to this problem. Perhaps we could build one, but doing it correctly would require developer involvement. A community-developed solution would be limited to batching and submitting edits from the account of someone who has already earned editing privileges. (Batching is necessary to prevent massive disruptions, given that editing always bumps posts.)

Comment: @CodyGray unless you're Jon Skeet, then [everything is possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237146/158100) ... ;)

Comment: Domain registration doesn't lapse until 2021-04-02T21:45:48Z

Comment: @MartinSmith That doesn't necessarily mean anything useful, e.g. the site bobpowell dot net is still going but [it isn't what it once was](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402392/fixing-up-now-bad-links-to-use-wayback-machine) (I'm currently half-way through updating the links on SO to point to the Wayback Machine.)

Comment: It was in response to the part in the Q " in case the problem is that the registration has lapsed"

Comment: Shog9 has rewritten URLs before in a reversible way, see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367342/7296893). I'm not sure if that counts as "there's an automated solution" or "there probably is a script on a hard drive somewhere that worked at some time for one specific domain, written by someone that no longer works here, and digging it up and getting it to work might be more work than creating a new one from scratch"

Comment: And that we would no longer be allowed to use anyway, @Erik, since there's no one left who is accessible to us and has that level of access.

Comment: Just to state the obvious: Posts must stand on their own, and only rely on their own content. Ideally, text content, also sometimes an image might be required. They should not require following a link. If this causes an actual problem for any post, then that post should not have been on [main] anyway, i.e. as a question, it is unclear, as an answer it is unhelpful. Of course, links with auxiliary information that lead to nowhere are annoying, and it would be nice if they didn't, but if there is any post that gets *broken* by this, then it was already broken before.

Comment: @JörgWMittag — the vast majority of the answers quote the site (cite the site?) and contain a link to “this is where the information came from”.  That is my standard modus operandi; I believe most other answers are similar.  Therefore, they are not incomplete or unusable because the relevant text is included, but it is harder for an interested reader to study the context of the quote with port70.net gone AWO.

Comment: A note on C11: open-std.org hosts a copy as well: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: @Siguza — the disadvantage of the PDF is that you can't give a URL that goes direct to the correct section, even paragraph.  Otherwise, it is an impeccable source.

Comment: Looks like the site is back

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually you can link to a section in the PDF by taking the link from the bookmark section, eg http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A1170%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D points to Annex G; it is just not a very reable link

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: When I tried that URL, it went to the start of the document, not Annex G.  Not the very start; it went to the start of Section 1 Scope, on p19 of 701 of the PDF file (using the PDF display in Chrome on a Mac).  I am also unsure how to generate the URL from the PDF display — activating the bookmark list, selecting a section and popping up the menu doesn't show a 'copy URL' option.  I think there's something in what you say, but I'm not sure how I should be using it in my environment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Interesting, it works for me on Firefox (on Windows), but indeed not on Chrome.

Comment: You could also try linking to a page, like http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=550

Comment: As of 2022-07-29T12:15:00-06:00 (a Friday), the [port70.net](http://port70.net/) site appears to be down again (same error in Chrome), and it has not been available for some hours now.  It's probably appropriate to wait until at least Tuesday before doing anything about it.  (I'd forgotten about this — I just did a search in MSO for 'port70' and this popped up.)

Comment: And, as of 2022-07-29T22:50:00-06:00, the site is back online.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a script to mass update URLs, as long as the updates follow a simple pattern like prefixing with `https://web.archive.org/web/` which seems to work here. @ErikA mentioned [a case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367342/4751173) were former Community Manager Shog9 did this, but the new team does these changes too, see [this recent example](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1995/7988) on Hinduism Stack Exchange.

Perhaps one of the ♦ moderators can (after the holidays) ping a Community Manager to point at this thread.